# Checkbox styling - targeting a specific input element

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

Within a series of check boxes (lets say 3 options) I am looking to target a specific input element on the checking/unchecking of the associated label.

**HAML**

```
.choice-select-button
  = check_box_tag("order[recipes][]", recipe.id, selected)
  = label_tag do
    = t(".step_4.tick_box_to_select")
```

**Renders HTML**

```
<div class="choice-select-button">
  <input type="checkbox" name="order[recipes][]" id="order_recipes_" value="6" checked="checked">
  <label>Click to select</label>
</div>
```

Each `<input>` is assigned same id, namely `id="order_recipes_"` so if I give set `<label for="order_recipes_">` and the user then 'un-checks' the label then only the first input on the page with the `id="order_recipes_"` is styled according to my css instructions.

The only differentiator I can see for the `choice-select-button.input` is it's value. As such I was looking at giving the label a `for=` that targets `inputs` with the `id="order_recipes_` AND `value="6"`. First up, is this doable, and secondly, is the best way to do something like this or is there a much more simple method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rrails doc:

> check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {}) Link
>   Creates a check box form input tag.
>
> Options
>
> :disabled - If set to true, the user will not be able to use this
>   input.
>
> Any other key creates standard HTML options for the tag.

you can generate different ids like this:

```
check_box_tag("order[recipes][]", recipe.id, selected, {id: recipe.id})
```